# Set rounded corners on UIimage in UICollectionViewCell in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, viewcontroller, collectionview

I have a simple problem that I cannot find a solution to on google, the docs or here.

I have a Collectionview in my view controller. I have created a custom cell, DescriptionCell, that contains a UIImage. I want this image to have rounded corners. However, I don't know where to set the cornerradius on the UIImage layer. I have tried in the cells' awakeFromNib method, in the delegate method CellForRowAtIndexPath and overriden LayoutSubview in the cell but it does not work.
Where should I put the code to set the radius for the UIImage?

To specify, I know how to create rounded corners of a UIImage. But if it is a subview of a Collectionview cell, I do not know where to set the cornerradius.

Here is code for my descriptionCell

```
class DescriptionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var mImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
    //mImage.layer.cornerradius = 5 
    //Does not work, the image is still square in the cell
    }
```

And in the cellforRowAtIndePath

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
var cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("descriptioncell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DescriptionCell
    //cell.mImage.layer.cornerradius = 5 
    //Does not work, the image is still square in the cell
return cell    
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making round corners for a UIImage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938800/making-round-corners-for-a-uiimage)

Comment: Nope this is different. I am already using the code from that answer. MY question is where to put UIImage.layer.cornerradius = xxx?

Comment: Update your question with relevant code.

Comment: There is no specific code that would make sense to add. My question is really simple: how do I create a UIImage with rounded corners that lies in a UICollectionViewCell.

Comment: @Jell92 It would make sense to at least add the code for your `DescriptionCell` and `CellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I have just added the code:)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well you're using part of the code from the answer you said you were using.
the other part is `imageView.clipsToBounds = true`

Update your `awakeFromNib` like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    mImage.layer.cornerRadius = 5 
    mimage.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

---

To make it a circle you need to set cornerRadius to half of the square height. In your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` add these lines:

```
cell.layoutIfNeeded()
cell.mImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.mImage.frame.height/2
```

**Update**

To avoid `layoutSubviews` from being called twice, override `layoutSubviews` in your `DescriptionCell` class and put the code there:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    layoutIfNeeded()
    mImage.layer.cornerRadius = mImage.frame.height/2
}
```

Comment: I think that did the trick! Now however comes another problem, I want it to be circle shaped. I know that the code is something like:   mImage.layer.cornerRadius = mImage.frame.width/2 But when I use this it does not work. The image dissapears!

Comment: Setting the corner radius to be based on the frame needs to be done much after the call to `awakeFromNib`. It needs to be done after the cell has been sized and the image has been set.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! And when is that exactly? In what method can I set it then?

Comment: you can call some configure function on cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` or even better at `willDisplayCell`

Comment: Thanks for all the help Sam, that was exactly the answer I was looking for! So the LayoutifNeeded forces the view to setup its subviews immediately?

Comment: @Jell92 You're welcome:) Yes that is exactly what it does. But this way it'll end up laying out the subviews again after `willDisplayCell` has finished. you can override the `layoutSubviews` method of the Cell to avoid that. i'll update my answer.

Comment: Hm ok, but if LayoutIfNeeded() calls our implementation of LayoutSubviews wouldn't that just be recursion - since LayoutSubviews would call itself?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried placing it inside the custom UICollectionViewCell's init function?

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    image.layer.masksToBounds = true
    image.layer.cornerRadius = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an extension like:

```
extension UIView {
    func addBorder(color: UIColor, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 10, borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0) {
        layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}
```